# Static generator in Drupal 7 was error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I use module https://www.drupal.org/project/static in Drupal 7, when I click on publish, a lot of files were error, and the link in all Html that generated are wrong. Please help me how to configure this module to export all drupal site. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example wrong link and any configuration you have used in the Static module?

Comment: - All static files are generated in:  .static\normal\
- The link image in html page is: /sites/all/themes/my_theme/logo.png (wrong link, It should .static/normal/sites/all/themes/my_theme/logo.png)
- In html page I have a  menu like: menu 1 (mydomain/node/1) this link is the view and I made alias  is mydomain/aboutus . But the menu link in html still node/1 ...